# How do I make a field read only using code in APEX and LWC?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

So basically I want to make a field of an object Read only given some conditions. For example, lets say I have a field called "Description" and an object called Account. Account also has a field called "Class", and lets say I want description to be read only when "Class" is Vard.

I would assume that you would have to import an APEX METHOD into LWC with the METHOD LIKE THIS:

```
SELECT Description, Class FROM Account WHERE Class ='Vard'
```

This would select all the description where class is = Vard, but then how would I make this field read only?

Comment: Do you want to display the field's value in a lightning web component? What are you trying to achieve? Or do you mean you want the field value to be read only on a page layout regardless?

Comment: So, I want to make the Description field to be read only for  account's where the class is Vard

Comment: It is not clear what you mean with read-only, as Arthlete says. Read-only for a user interface build with visualforce, for a user interface build with LWC, a page layout, or what exactly?

Comment: I want it to be read only for a specific page layout

Comment: @JasonChau Why are you mentioning LWC if you are trying to lock the field for a specific page layout?

Comment: Sorry I got a little confused with the instructions. I want to lock a field based on some conditions and I was wondering on how to do that.

Comment: Why not write a Validation Rule?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking for a page layout here is a solution that I have used. However, it's not using APEX or LWC but it may be what you're looking for.

1. Create another Record Type for `Account` and assign a new page layout to it.
2. On this page layout you make the `Class__c` field Read-Only. *I will use the `Owner` field from my sandbox since I don't have a `Class__c` field on the Account object.*
   [image]

*Once you save the field properties the field will appear with a lock next to it to indicate that it's read-only for that page layout.*

[image]

3. Create a workflow rule or add to a process builder. `IF Class ='Vard'` then update Record Type.

*Here is an example in a Process Builder. Below we are setting the criteria. Remember it has to be for every time a record is created and edited. The same would go for a Workflow Rule.*

[image]

*Next we are changing the Record Type of that record using the Update Field Action.*

[image]

If the Class field gets changed to "Vard" the process builder is going to kick in and update the Record Type for that record.

As a result, it will change the page layout associated to that Record Type.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the field to be read-only on the record's standard page layout, I can see an argument for using @SFAdmin's answer.

But if you're building a Lightning Web Component anyway -- i.e. you are already taking the plunge and doing custom code instead of configuration for the UI where you want the Description field to be read-only -- implementing this in LWC is pretty straightforward.  You just set the `disabled` (or if you prefer, `read-only`) attribute on the Description field to a getter that returns whether the class is "Vard".

HTML Template

```html
<template>
    <lightning-input 
        label="Description" 
        data-field="description"
        value={description}
        disabled={classIsVard}
        onchange={handleChange}
    ></lightning-input>
    <lightning-input 
        label="Class" 
        data-field="classField"
        value={classField}
        onchange={handleChange}
    ></lightning-input>
</template>
```

JavaScript Controller

```js
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
    @track description;
    @track classField;

    handleChange(event) {
        this[event.target.dataset.field] = event.target.value;
    }

    get classIsVard() {
        return this.classField === 'Vard';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help.